# Can't access a column?

Tags: java, android

My code is meant to retrieve a song from a list with 5 columns (id, title, singers, year (of release) and stars). But I for some reason can't retrieve that last one.

So I made a Song Class:

```
package com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class song {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String singers;
    private int year;
    private int stars;

    public song (int id,
    String title,
    String singers,
    int year,
    int stars
    ){
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;
        this.singers=singers;
        this.year=year;
        this.stars=stars;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getStars() {
        return stars;
    }

    public String getSingers() {
        return singers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "\n" + title+"\n"+year + "\n" + stars + "\n" + singers;
    }

}
```

This class is meant to intreact with MainActivity:

```
package com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnInsert, btnGetSongs;
    TextView tvResults;

    EditText YearInput;
    EditText SongInput;
    EditText SingerInput;
    RadioGroup RadioGroupRating;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        btnGetSongs = findViewById(R.id.btnGetTasks);
        //List View->
        YearInput=findViewById(R.id.insertYear);
        SongInput=findViewById(R.id.insertTitle);
        SingerInput=findViewById(R.id.insertSingers);
        RadioGroupRating=findViewById(R.id.radio_group);


        btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                String title=SongInput.getText().toString();
                String singers=SingerInput.getText().toString();
                int year=Integer.parseInt(YearInput.getText().toString());

                int selectedRatingId=RadioGroupRating.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton selectedRatingButton=findViewById(selectedRatingId);
                int rating=Integer.parseInt(selectedRatingButton.getText().toString());
                db.insertSong(title,singers,year,rating);

                SongInput.setText("");
                SingerInput.setText("");
                YearInput.setText("");
                RadioGroupRating.clearCheck();
            }
        });

        btnGetSongs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Create the DBHelper object, passing in the
                // activity's Context
                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

                // Insert a task
                ArrayList<song> data = db.getSongs();
                db.close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                //Label the actual editactivity EditActivity2
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }


}
```

which is supplemented by DBHelper:

```
package com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {    // Start version with 1
    // increment by 1 whenever db schema changes.
    private static final int DATABASE_VER = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_SONG = "song";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String COLUMN_SINGERS = "singers";
    private static final String COLUMN_YEAR="year";
    private static final String COLUMN_STARS="stars";
    // Filename of the database
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "songs.db";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableSql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SONG +  "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_SINGERS+ " TEXT ,"
                + COLUMN_YEAR + " INTEGER,"
                + COLUMN_STARS+"INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(createTableSql);
        Log.i("info" ,"created tables");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SONG);
        // Create table(s) again
        onCreate(db);


    }
    public void insertSong(String title, String singers, int year, int stars){

        // Get an instance of the database for writing
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // We use ContentValues object to store the values for
        //  the db operation
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Store the column name as key and the description as value
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        values.put(COLUMN_SINGERS, singers);
        values.put(COLUMN_YEAR, year);
        values.put(COLUMN_STARS, stars);

        // Store the column name as key and the date as value

        // Insert the row into the TABLE_TASK
        db.insert(TABLE_SONG, null, values);
        // Close the database connection
        db.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<song> getSongs() {
        ArrayList<song> tasks = new ArrayList<song>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_SINGERS,COLUMN_YEAR,COLUMN_STARS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SONG, columns, null, null, null, null,  null , null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID);
                String title= String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE));
                String singers= String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SINGERS));
                @SuppressLint("Range") int year = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_YEAR));
                @SuppressLint("Range") int stars = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_STARS));
                song obj = new song(id, title, singers,year,stars);
                tasks.add(obj);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return tasks;
    }

}
```

And for good measure, here the xml of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Input1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/insertTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/InputPrompt1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Input2" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/insertSingers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/InputPrompt2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Input3" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/insertYear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/InputPrompt3"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Input4" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Input4.1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Input4.2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Input4.3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Input4.4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Input4.5" />

    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnInsert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FinalButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetTasks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ViewListings" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

My intent was pressing btnRetrieve would cause a list to display in a separate activity.

The Activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and its java coding

```
package com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<song> songsList;
    ArrayAdapter<song> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
        lv=findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        songsList = dbHelper.getSongs();
        ArrayList<String> songTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            song song = songsList.get(i);
            songTitles.add(song.getTitle());
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(EditActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,songsList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it caused this to appear in my logcat:

```
2023-07-17 09:00:34.942  2045-2045  SQLiteLog               com...tiondev.android.songdbmanager  E  (1) no such column: stars in "SELECT id, title, singers, year, stars FROM song"
2023-07-17 09:00:34.945  2045-2045  AndroidRuntime          com...tiondev.android.songdbmanager  D  Shutting down VM
2023-07-17 09:00:34.988  2045-2045  AndroidRuntime          com...tiondev.android.songdbmanager  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager, PID: 2045
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: stars (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT id, title, singers, year, stars FROM song
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1263)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                                                                                                        at com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager.DBHelper.getSongs(DBHelper.java:78)
                                                                                                        at com.myapplicationdev.android.songdbmanager.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible problems that I see:

1. When you create the table you do: `COLUMN_STARS+"INTEGER)";`, it must be `COLUMN_STARS+" INTEGER)";`, I suppose? The space is missing before `INTEGER`
2. Are you sure that the table was created and you see your `created tables` statement in logs? Just to make sure that the table for really created with the last version of the code.

I hope it helps.